# Sublime text highlighting for webpack

Tags: webpack, sublimetext3, package-control

I want my webpack.config.js to highlight the right characters. How to do it in sublime? because my text is like this. and it doesn't highlight well the characters. [image]

Comment: Not exact answer but You can use any ES6 or Babel plugin which can highlight this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your sublime to the latest one. It will work.